Link to page word addin
I created a little word addin and it works well.
However, I would like to build multi pages and quickly navigate to them. So I added a « test.html » to my task pane folder. Then I added a 
Then, when I click on the link, it says that he cannot get test.html
It tried to add « ../«  or something like that to the href and it didn’t work either.
